# How to use less memory in Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Tags: c++, memory, profiling, primes

I'm coding on a leetcode-like platform. There is a task: counter the number of primes below a given bound.

I used the algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

I copy the code from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/ , except that I make `false` represents `isPrime` to avoid using `memset`. Here is my code:

```
void SieveOfEratosthenes(int n) 
{ 
    bool *prime = new bool[n+1]();  // initialized by false by default  

    for (int p=2; p*p<=n; p++) 
    { 
        if (prime[p] == false) 
        { 
            for (int i=p*p; i<=n; i += p) 
                prime[i] = true; 
        } 
    } 

    for (int p=2; p<=n; p++) 
       if (prime[p]) 
          cout << p << " "; 
}
```

However, when I execute it, the platform tells me that I used too much memory in the case of `100 000 000` as the enter.

I've checked that `sizeof(bool)` equals to `1`.

Is there some way to use less memory for this piece of code?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112227/optimization-on-sieve-of-eratosthenes-using-vectorbool

Comment: @JamesKPolk  well, I think I've used all ways in that post.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` uses 1 *bit* per element, so uses 1/8 the storage of an array of bool.

Comment: @JamesKPolk  ohh, got it. Let me try.

Comment: As an added bonus, `vector` won't leak all of that memory you're forgetting to `delete[]`. You've got a pretty good-sized leak going on there.

Comment: @JamesKPolk  it works!  thanks

Comment: You should try implementing the segmented sieve of Eratosthenes? It’s main goal is to reduce memory use.

Comment: @JosephWood ... and thus speed it up considerably, by letting that memory fit into the cache. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

- use a bit array representing only odd numbers
- break the problem up into segments so the partial sieve uses much less memory

@Kim Walish has a fast C++ version here:

https://github.com/kimwalisch/primesieve/wiki/Segmented-sieve-of-Eratosthenes

You can make it use less memory still by always limiting the segment size to the L1 cache size, and by changing the IsPrime array to also be a bit array of odd numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a memory optimized implementation of the sieve of eratosthenes. The basic idea is that, you only need to store the status of the odd numbers. Rest of it is similar to the normal implementation.

```
#include <iostream>

class Solution {
public:
    int countPrimes(int n) {
        //if(n <= 1) return 0; // including n
        if(n <= 2) return 0; // number of primes less than 0 / 1 / 2 is 0
        const int MAXN = 1500000 + 5; // adjust MAXN accordingly
        // finding prime from 1 up to N
        int status[(MAXN >> 1) + 1]; // we need space for only the odd numbers
        // works well up to 1.5 * 10 ^ 6, for numbers larger than that, you need to adjust the second operand accordingly
        int prime[115000 + 1000]; // prime number distribution , pi(x) = x/ (ln(x) - 1) , adjust this according to MAXN

        // If status[i] = 0 -> i is prime
        // If status[i] = 1 -> i is not prime

        for(int i = 1 ; i <= (n >> 1) ; ++i) status[i] = 0; // for every i , 2 * i + 1 is the odd number, marking it as prime

        int sqrtN = static_cast <int> ((sqrt (static_cast <double> (n))));
        // computing sqrt(N) only once because it is costly computing it inside a loop

        // only accounting the odd numbers and their multiples
        for(int i = 3 ; i <= sqrtN ; i += 2){
            if(status[i >> 1] == 0){
                // if this is still a prime then discard its multiples
                // first multiple that needs to be discarded starts at i * i
                // all the previous ones have already been discarded
                for(int j = i * i ; j <= n ; j += (i + i)) {
                    //printf("Marking %d as not prime\n",j);
                    status[j >> 1] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        int counter = 0;
        prime[counter++] = 2;
        for(int i = 3 ; i <= n ; i += 2){
            if(status[i >> 1] == 0){
                prime[counter++] = i;
            }
        }

        if( (n & 1) && !status[n >> 1]) counter--; // if n is prime, discard n

        std::cout << "Number of primes less than " << n << " is " << counter << "\n";
        for(int i = 0 ; i < counter; ++i){
            std::cout << prime[i];
            if(i != counter - 1) std::cout << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";

        return counter;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Solution solution;
    int n; std::cin >> n; 
    solution.countPrimes(n);
    return 0;
}
```